# What does "safe" mean in smart contract engineering?

Tags: solidity, security, conventions

Many times there are duplicate codes. For example, one function is `safeTransfer` and the other is `Transfer`. Another example is `token` vs `safeToken`. What is this naming convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the 'safe' version is another implementation which does what the original function does, but in a bit more secure manner.

If we take the example of 'safeTransfer', the 'safe' version does a regular transfer but also checks for required return values. Some old ERC20 token implementations for example don't return a boolean value upon a transfer, and `safeTransfer` takes this into account when determining whether the transfer failed or not.

So the 'safe' versions are alternative versions which you may use if you are concerned about certain security aspects of the original functions.

Just don't be fooled by a random function calling itself 'safe'. Any function can have any name (barring the names required by standards) and having the string 'safe' in the function name doesn't make it any more safe by default. It's not uncommon for malicious functions to have a 'safe' name to try to trick users.

Answer (score 2):

Naming things is [hard](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/has-phil-karlton-ever-said-there-are-only-two-hard-things-in-computer-science) in computer science.

As a programmer, it is important to understand what "safe" means, there is no convention, and you should read the code and ask around.  As a user calling a smart contract, you should ask programmers you trust for help, just like you would ask a doctor about medicines.

Here is an article that shows dangers of code that was named "safe":

https://samczsun.com/the-dangers-of-surprising-code

> For a developer, a safe function might mean that it doesn't contain any bugs or introduce additional security concerns. For a user, it could mean that it contains additional guardrails to protect them from accidentally shooting themselves in the foot.

> It turns out that in this case, these functions are more of the latter and less of the former. This is especially unfortunate because given the choice between transfer and safeTransfer, why wouldn't you pick the safe one? It's in the name!

> Well, one reason might be our old friend reentrancy, or as I've been trying my hardest to rebrand it to: unsafe external calls. Recall that any external call is potentially unsafe if the recipient is attacker-controlled because the attacker may be able to cause your contract to transition into an undefined state. By design, these "safe" functions perform an external call to the recipient of the tokens, which is often controlled by the sender during a mint or transfer. In other words, this is practically a textbook example of an unsafe external call.

The article concludes:

> Code that's surprising may break things in catastrophic ways. In both of these cases, developers who reasonably assumed that the safe class of functions would be (at least as) safe to use instead inadvertently increased their attack surface. As the ERC-721 and ERC-1155 standards become more popular and widespread, it is very likely that this will become an increasingly frequent occurrence. Developers will need to consider the risks of using the safe class of functions and determine how the external call might interact with the code they've written.

Answer (score 1):

Things like safeMath (now outdated since solidity 0.8) are a generic protocol for conventional operations - e.g. multiplication - which have been developed by reliable bodies to ensure minimal security risk.

If you see something without the ‘safe’ prefix, it sometimes means these developers have created a methodology of their own.